# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden on container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync() method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

```
 static class StorageUtils
    {
        public static CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount
        {
            get
            {
                string account = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountName"];
                //string account = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountName");

                //string key = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountAccessKey");
                string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountName"];
                string connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", account, key);
                return CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a web project and I converted it to "MS Azure Cloud Service Project"

I make the Azure project default and run CreateAndConfigureAsync() to create the container.
It works fine and creates the images container in Azure storage.

Then I make my web project default and change `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` in StorageUtils class and run the web app project.
Then I get "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" error when 
`container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()` line get executed.

What is the reason for this?

```
async public void CreateAndConfigureAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = StorageUtils.StorageAccount;

                // Create a blob client and retrieve reference to images container
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

                // Create the "images" container if it doesn't already exist.
                if (await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
                {
                    // Enable public access on the newly created "images" container
                    await container.SetPermissionsAsync(
                        new BlobContainerPermissions
                        {
                            PublicAccess =
                                BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                        });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {            }
        }
```

I'm following coding on 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#upload-blob

Comment: Have you defined `StorageAccountName` and `StorageAccountAccessKey` in web.config file and can you check if they are proper?

Comment: Yes, both values are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first code snippet:

```
string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountName"];
```

This should be:

```
string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountAccessKey"];
```

Comment: Careless coding. So is there any limitation in the length of file name while I'm uploading files. It means Azure generate an url for each file, if I upload a file which has lengthy file name will it be an issue when generating the url?

Comment: The naming limitations can be found here: [Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx)